# Remote script cannot decode json but is receiving it correctly

Tags: json

I have a script on one server which is posting a json array to another server which is not decoding it. I printed the POST and see that it's receiving it correctly but then it's not able to decode it. This is what I tested with, it prints the sent json array but isn't decoding it.

```
    print_r($_POST);
    $inputArray = json_decode($_POST['inputarray'], TRUE);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($inputArray);
```

Comment: That's nice. What's the JSON?

Comment: It was working on my local server but not the remote server which was strange. I found stripping slashes in fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by stripping slashes. On my local server it was working but not the remote server which was strange. Found out this works.

```
    $inputstring = stripslashes($_POST['inputarray']);
    $inputArray = json_decode($inputstring, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your data json encoded, if yes then check for errors, try:

```
$json  = json_encode($text);
$error = json_last_error();

var_dump($json, $error);
```